# How to insert separators between TabBar items of UITabBarController

Tags: swift

I am adding separator views between TabBar items using following code. They are visible in iPhone but not in iPad.

```
//Add seprators Line
    if let items = self.tabBar.items {
        //Get the height of the tab bar            
        let height = self.tabBar.bounds.height
        //Calculate the size of the items
        let numItems = CGFloat(items.count)
        let itemSize = CGSize(
            width: tabBar.frame.width / numItems,
            height: tabBar.frame.height)

        for (index, _) in items.enumerated() {
            //We don't want a separator on the left of the first item.
            if index > 0 {
                //Xposition of the item
                let xPosition = itemSize.width * CGFloat(index)
                /* Create UI view at the Xposition,
                 with a width of 0.5 and height equal
                 to the tab bar height, and give the
                 view a background color
                 */
                let separator = UIView(frame: CGRect(
                    x: xPosition, y: 0, width: 0.5, height: height))
                separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
                tabBar.insertSubview(separator, at: 1)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked. This what I used:

```
self.tabBar.itemPositioning =  UITabBarItemPositioning.fill
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Here is a Perfect Solution  #

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tabBar.itemPositioning = .fill
        ChangeOrientation(width: self.tabBar.bounds.width)
}
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator :UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        removeSperator()
        ChangeOrientation(width: size.width)
}
func removeSperator() {
        if let items = self.tabBar.items {
            for (index, _) in items.enumerated() {
                //We don't want a separator on the left of the first item.
                if index > 0 {
                    if let viewWithTag = tabBar.viewWithTag(index) {
                        //print("index for remove : \(index)")
                        viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
                    }
                    else {
                        print("tag not found")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}

func ChangeOrientation(width : CGFloat) {
        if let items = self.tabBar.items {
            //Get the height of the tab bar
            let height = self.tabBar.bounds.height
            //Calculate the size of the items
            let numItems = CGFloat(items.count)
            let itemSize = CGSize(
                width: width / numItems,
                height: tabBar.frame.height)
            for (index, _) in items.enumerated() {
                //We don't want a separator on the left of the first item.
                if index > 0 {
                    //Xposition of the item
                    let xPosition = itemSize.width * CGFloat(index)
                    /* Create UI view at the Xposition,
                     with a width of 0.5 and height equal
                     to the tab bar height, and give the
                     view a background color
                     */
                    //print("index : \(index)")
                    let separator = UIView(frame: CGRect(
                        x: xPosition, y: 0, width: 0.5, height: height))
                    separator.tag = index
                    separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                    tabBar.insertSubview(separator, at: 1)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function written in **SWIFT 5.0**

```
fileprivate func addSeparatorToTabBar() {
    if let items = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items {

        //Get the height of the tab bar

        let height = (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.bounds)!.height

        //Calculate the size of the items

        let numItems = CGFloat(items.count)
        let itemSize = CGSize(
            width: (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.width)! / numItems,
            height: (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height)!)

        for (index, _) in items.enumerated() {

            //We don't want a separator on the left of the first item.

            if index > 0 {

                //Xposition of the item

                let xPosition = itemSize.width * CGFloat(index)

                /* Create UI view at the Xposition,
                 with a width of 0.5 and height equal
                 to the tab bar height, and give the
                 view a background color
                 */
                let separator = UIView(frame: CGRect(
                    x: xPosition, y: 0, width: 0.5, height: height))
                separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
                self.tabBarController?.tabBar.insertSubview(separator, at: 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and call it in **viewDidLoad()**

```
addSeparatorToTabBar()
```